# Flutter - Does a stream only read new documents?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

If I have for example a `Stream` of type `QuerySnapshot` which is subscribing on a collection of documents and now new documents are added to the collection does the `Stream` only read the new ones or is it rereading the whole collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking. If you are subscribing to a `Stream` and you get your `Stream` of `QuerySnapshots` back you can either choose to reload the entire database every time a new document is added or changed or just get new documents.

```
//Just gets new documents
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection(//Collection).snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
            if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
                   //This is the difference
              List<DocumentChange> snapshot =
                  asyncSnapshot.data.documentChanges;
              snapshot.forEach((DocumentChange change) {}

//Get all documents
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Test').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
            if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
                 //This is the difference
              List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot =
                  asyncSnapshot.data.documents;
              snapshot.forEach((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
```

**DocumentChange**
An array of the documents that changed since the last snapshot. If this is the first snapshot, all documents will be in the list as Added changes.
**DocumentSnapshot**
Gets a list of all documents every time a new document is added or changed.

Keep in mind like @Doug Stevenson said you get charged for every added or changed document.

Comment: so using documentChanges is only for performance purpose, in sense of document reads both options don't differ right?

Comment: Using ```DocumentChange``` will result in less document reads as you are only reading new or updated documents

Comment: yeah sure, but I was not expressing myself very well, I meant: If you want to display all documents in the collection and on stream start you get all documents, add it to a specified list and pass it to a displaying widget and then if smth in the collection changes: for each DocumentChange you would add/replace/remove the document in the specified list. This may increase the performance, but wouldn't differ in reads.

Comment: You would have to be dealing with a very large amount of documents to actually notice a performance increase but your logic is correct less documents to deal with so less computations to process.

Answer (score 1):

Each newly added or changed document costs another read.